# Openshift Gitlab runner http access

Tags: openshift, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self hosted gitlab instance which is accessible on HTTP. I have Openshift cluster for orchestrating our workloads. In order to setup CI pipelines, we opted for gitlab runners operrator on openshift to run gitlab pipelines.

Can gitlab runners operator instance connects to the gitlab instance on http(80) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GitLab Runners are connected with GitLab Instances using http/https connections. When you are configuring the runner, make sure to provide the URL of the GitLab Instance and that it is accessible from GitLab Instance Host Machine.

For you reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/configuring_runner_operator.html